# Tui Calendar Ajax

Tags: javascript, calendar, fetch-api

I have a really weird problem that i can't figure out.

If i create schedules outside a request, all is fine, so this:

```
   me.calendar = new tui.Calendar(document.getElementById(`${me.id}-calendar`), {
        defaultView: 'week',
        taskView: false,
        useCreationPopup: true,
        useDetailPopup: true,
        week: {
            daynames: ['Du', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Jo', 'Vi', 'Sa'],
            narrowWeekend: false,
            startDayOfWeek: 1
        }
    });

    let startDate = new Date(me.calendar.getDateRangeStart()._date);
    let endDate = new Date(me.calendar.getDateRangeEnd()._date);

    me.calendar.createSchedules(events);
```

works just as expected. However, if those events are dynamically loaded from the server like this:

```
   me.calendar = new tui.Calendar(document.getElementById(`${me.id}-calendar`), {
        defaultView: 'week',
        taskView: false,
        useCreationPopup: true,
        useDetailPopup: true,
        week: {
            daynames: ['Du', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Jo', 'Vi', 'Sa'],
            narrowWeekend: false,
            startDayOfWeek: 1
        }
    });

    let startDate = new Date(me.calendar.getDateRangeStart()._date);
    let endDate = new Date(me.calendar.getDateRangeEnd()._date);

    fetch('/get-events?startDate=' + startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0] + '&endDate=' + endDate.toISOString().split('T')[0], {
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
    }).then(function (response) {
        response.json().then(function (response) {
            me.calendar.createSchedules(response.events);
        });
    });
```

the schedules are created, that i am sure of, but the problem is that for some reason, the height of the calendar is set to 0 and i can't figure out why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for anyone still facing this issue i solved it by adding

```
me.calendar.toggleScheduleView(true);
```

after the creation of the schedules